# Private class properties in type comparison

Tags: typescript

In general, types in `TypeScript` are `structural`. However, according to  [The `TypeScript` manual](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook), when testing two classes for compatibility, private properties are required to come from the same hierarchy. What is the reason for this restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This restriction is the only way to [create unmatchable types in TypeScript](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2014/12/why-private-members-result-in-unmatchable-typescript-structures/).

You can create an interface to represent the shared type if you need to (code taken from the article linked)...

```
interface GeneralId {
    getId() : number;
}

class CustomerId {
    constructor(private id: number) {}

    getId() { return this.id; }
}

class ProductId {
    constructor(private id: number) {}

    getId() { return this.id; }
}

function nonSpecificMethod(id: GeneralId) {
    //...
}

var id1 = new CustomerId(1);
var id2 = new ProductId(2);

// Type passes
nonSpecificMethod(id1);

// Type passes
nonSpecificMethod(id2);
```

In this example, a `CustomerId` cannot be used in place of a `ProductId` (this is the point of creating this kind of wrapper class). If wish to allow them to be interchangeable, you can use the `GeneralId` type instead.